# Windows Boot CD to read and write NTFS

Tags: windows, boot, virus, compact-disc

My laptop got some virus etc. I have a clean ghost image of the laptop (.gho file) on another drive. I would like to restore the image, but Ghost wouldnt run on XP, it says it needs to be on DOS mode.

So i prepared a boot cd, but the boot cd would not read any drive other than itself.

How do I run Ghost now? All I need to do is, apply the clean ghost image back onto my laptop.

All help appreciated.

Comment: What version of Ghost are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Er, this is really not the forum for this--rather, you should post at the sister site, SuperUser.com.

But in short, what you need is a Windows PE bootable disk, like [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), [Reatogo](http://www.reatogo.de/REATOGO.htm), or [UBCD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) (this last one is probably the easiest).

Answer (score 0):

Ghost can create a boot disk that runs itself. There must be Create a Rescue Disk menu item somewhere in the program.